# is the DENSE_RANK()" function applicable in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, dense-rank

Does the following MySQL code or "DENSE_RANK()" function works in MySQL or is it only used in Oracle database ???

```
Select Employee, Cost_Center, Cost_Grant, Percent
,DENSE_RANK() over (PARTITION BY Employee order by Percent ASC) as Rank
```

| Employee | Cost_Center | Cost_Grant | Percent |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| AB61526 | 10030 |  | 54 |
| AB61526 | 14020 |  | 46 |
| AB60020 |  | 1040 | 68 |
| AB60020 | 10010 |  | 32 |
| AB60038 |  | 11000 | 71 |
| AB60038 | 10010 |  | 29 |
| AK50051 |  | 10020 | 23 |
| AK50051 |  | 11520 | 78 |

Expected results output:

| Employee | Cost_Center | Cost_Grant | Percent | Rank |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| AB61526 | 10030 |  | 54 | 1 |
| AB61526 | 14020 |  | 46 | 2 |
| AB60020 |  | 1040 | 68 | 2 |
| AB60020 | 10010 |  | 32 | 1 |
| AB60038 |  | 11000 | 71 | 2 |
| AB60038 | 10010 |  | 29 | 1 |
| AK50051 |  | 10020 | 23 | 1 |
| AK50051 |  | 11520 | 78 | 2 |

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-function-descriptions.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DENSE_RANK is supported in mysql beginning with version 8.0, and in MariaDB beginning with version 10.2.